# Cakephp 3.0 join in three table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to fetch the data from three table in cakephp 3.0 
There is three table 
1) size_category
2) sizes
3) sizerelations

Below is the file wise code 
Model SizeCategoryTable.php

```html
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('size_category');
        $this->displayField('sizeCat_Id');
        $this->primaryKey('sizeCat_Id');
  
  // used to associate the table with user table (join)  
  $this->belongsTo('Users', [
   'className' => 'Users',
   'foreignKey' => 'CreatedBy',
   'propertyName' => 'user'
  ]);
  
  $this->hasMany(
   'Sizerelations', [
    'className' => 'Sizerelations',
    'foreignKey' => 'Scat_Id',
    'propertyName' => 'sizerelations'
   ]   
  );
    }
```

Controller SizeCategoryController

```html
public function index($id = null)
    {
  $customQuery = $this->SizeCategory->find('all', array(
   'contain' => array(
    'Users',
    'Sizerelations' => array(
     'Sizes' => array(
      'fields' => array('id', 'Size_Code')
     )
    )
   )
  ));
  //debug();die();  
  
        $this->set('sizeCategory', $this->paginate($customQuery));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['sizeCategory']);
}
```

**I am greeting the error of Sizerelations is not associated with Sizes**

Comment: the relationship between `sizeraltions` and `sizes` is defined in *SizeRelationsTable.php*. Did you set it?

Comment: also consider following cakephp conventions and use plural forms for tables and controllers: `SizeCategoriesTable`, `SizeCategoriesController` and so on...

Comment: SizeRelationsTable.php is not created because i create the sizeraltions table later manulay i did not use cake bake command for that should i need to create the "SizeRelationsTable.php" inside model ?

Comment: It's not clear at all what are the relationships between your models. Maybe what you want to do is `belongsToMany` instead of `hasMany`. But it's just a guess. Otherwise any relationship between sizeraltions and sizes must be defined in SizeRelationsTable.php

Comment: I am trying to use BelogTomany Because size_category contain multiple sizes and to maintain there relation i create new table  sizerelations

Comment: I don't see any belongsToMany definition in your code

Comment: I resolved it by re run the command cake bake all for size_category and serializations  and it work for me there miss configuration in table relation